Issue with Accessing Local Storage in an iFrame for Single Sign-On (SSO) Project
I am working on a single sign-on (SSO) project using two React applications:

Sign-In React App: This app is hosted on a Tomcat server and saves session information in its local storage after signing in.
Local React App: This app is being developed locally and runs on localhost:3000. It contains an iframe that embeds the Tomcat-hosted Sign-In app.

Here’s the iframe code in my local React app:
<iframe
  id="sso-iframe"
  src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_SSO_DOMAIN}/sso/#/sso`}
  style={{ height: 1000, width: 1000 }}
  title="SSO Sync"
></iframe>

The Sign-In React App gets its own localstorage (the session after login), and POSTS a message to parent.
Steps Taken

After signing in to the Sign-In React App, I inspected its local storage, and it is populated with the session and user information.
However, when I return to my local React app and inspect the page, I can see both domain's local storage, but the Tomcat Sign-In React App’s local storage is empty.

CORS Configuration
I tried to configure the Tomcat server with the following CORS filter, but it does not seem to work:
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>3600</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Observations

When both apps run on localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 (Sign-In React-App), I can access the local storage correctly.
If I am able to inspect and see the correct local storage of both domain's current state displayed, then everything else should work.

Question
What could be causing the Tomcat-hosted Sign-In React App’s local storage to be empty in the iframe? How can I resolve this issue?

When it comes to sharing localStorage between an iframe and the page, there are significant privacy concerns due to third-party cookie and state
restrictions that modern browsers impose. The Storage Access API helps to
request access to third-party cookies and unpartitioned state(e.g: localstorage). Browsers may deny requests automatically unless previously granted or triggered by a user action.
Instead goin fully on that, a more straightforward method is to use the
window.postMessage() method for cross-origin communication which is widely supported.
Example:
Page:
// Listen for messages from the iframe
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.origin !== "https://my-iframe.com") return;
  console.log("Received from iframe:", event.data);
}, false);

Iframe:
// Post message
window.parent.postMessage(localStorage.getItem('someKey'), "https://my-iframe.com");


The Sign-In React App gets its own localstorage (the session after login), and POSTS a message to parent. The problem is its own localstorage is empty and not the same as the current state of the Sign-In React App opened in another tab.

@SoftwareNewbee The localstorage inside the iframe is not the same as in another page and it can't be. To understand why read: State partitioning...Firefox double-keys all client-side state by the origin of the resource being loaded and by the top-level site

Of course it is not the same, they are under different domain, but YOU would be able to see both localstorage of the current state of the domains when inspecting the webpage?

@SoftwareNewbee consider reading this answer... The localStorage property is unique to the window variable of the frame, it is not unique to the parent domain.... So why does Chromium block local storage in iframes.... In short the issue might just be your browser.

I'm pretty sure it discussing access localstorage from parent to child frame directly. The website in the iframe is getting its own localstorage, and posting as an message.
